# Is it safe to put a window a/c unit over kitchen sink window?

Tags: electrical, air-conditioning, safety

Pretty self explanatory. I have a small window unit that would fit right over my kitchen sink window. About 2.25' of clearance above the counter top. Just thinking being near a water source may be hazardous, but not really sure if that's over cautious given its clearance.

Comment: What wattage is it, and what circuit are you plugging it into?

Comment: "Fit right over my kitchen sink window"; would this be filling the bottom of the window, or are you trying to leave a viewing space underneath the A/C unit?

Comment: Ahhh, the old unfounded *"water source"* issue. Regardless of the logistical issues with an install like this, how is it any different than a counter top appliance with regard to the "water source"?

Comment: It's a 530 Watt 5k BTU going to a standard 120v GFI. It would be a standard fit to the bottom of the window. The window sill is just above the backsplash. @SPEEDY it's not leaking or anything, I was just kinda concerned about having a large appliance hanging over the sink where water has the potential of splashing back on it however unlikely.

Comment: See my answer below.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The inside workings of a window A/C are typically wet. The coils get tons of condensation, the fan in the back splashes the condensate water all over, it's fine there. If anything it is safer since it is being plugged into a GFCI protected receptacle where typically they are not.

Just be careful of the load and whatever else is plugged into the same circuit. You may need to turn off the A/C to use some appliances.

Comment: Yeah -- my main objection to it wouldn't be "it's in a potentially mildly damp location", it's "you're putting another big load on a SABC, which might put a crimp in your cooking style".

Comment: @ThreePhaseEel, actually, a 5k BTU, <5A load is not so bad. You could still easily run a coffee pot, mixer, blender, etc, with the A/C running. It's the 1800 watt toaster oven I'd worry about.

Comment: Yeah -- <5A is pretty good all in all -- a bigger A/C unit would be a worry though.